# How to prevent the top window in Qt from ever resizing due to the inner widgets changes?

Tags: qt

I suffer from this problem: my QWidget-derived top window has a lot of widgets inside. Sometimes these widgets "push" the top widget and it resizes outside of the screen.

The desired behavior is to never allow the top widget to resize due to the internal widget changes, but to still allow the user to resize the window.

How to achieve this desired behavior?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a QScrollArea

Comment: No, QScrollArea will show indiscriminately. I don't want it. I want widgets to pack inside the available area. Or maybe widgets themselves need to be changed?